# ¿package does not exist?

Tags: java, netbeans

Hola tengo este problema importando algunas cosas, estoy intentando usar hibernate, pero me aparecen estos errores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y estas son las librerias que me encuentro usando, necesito añadir ptras librerias o donde las puedo conseguir. Mirando otras preguntas  similares vi que mencionaban vaciar el cache, lo hice pero aun sigo con este problema. les agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: olvide mencionar que tambien importando un recurso de un packete que yo mismo hice dentro del proyecto.

Comment: ya puse la solución abajo ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes un error al momento de importar los paquetes, lo estas haciendo de esta manera:

```
import.java.util.List
```

El punto despues de la palabra `import` es incorrecto, debes hacerlo de esta forma:

```
import java.util.List
```

Comment: Muy cierto!!!! :o muchisimas gracias por tomarte tu tiempo y ayudarme, gracias!! :D

Comment: no hay problema bro :) dale como respuesta aceptada y voto arriba :D